# proof by induction : $n^n \ge 2^{n-1} n!$

Tags: analysis, induction

I am trying to show that
 $$\begin{matrix} n^n \ge 2^{n-1} n! & \text{(1)} \end{matrix}$$

I tried to solve it for n=n+1

$$(n+1)^{n+1}=(n+1)^n(n+1) \ge n^n(n+1) \ge 2^{n-1}n!(n+1)= 2^{n-1}(n+1)!$$

So I ended up having $2^{n-1}$, but I wanted $2^n$.

How can I prove $\text{(1)}$?

Comment: You should be careful - you mean, "... ended up having $2^{n-1}$, but I wanted $2^n$."

Comment: This earlier question might be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472220/prove-by-induction-dfracnn3nn-dfracnn2n/472933#472933

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** You spend too much using $(n+1)^n\geq n^n$ in the first inequality, try proving and using $(n+1)^n\geq 2n^n$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By Bernoulli you have

$$\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \geq 2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\color{#ff0000}{\large\left(n + 1\right)^{n + 1}}
\geq
{\left(n + 1\right)^{n + 1} \over n^{n}}\,2^{n -1}\,n!
=
\overbrace{\ \left(1 + {1 \over n}\right)^{n}\ }^{\geq\ 2}\quad 2^{n -1}\quad
\overbrace{\ \left(n + 1\right)n!\ }^{\left(n + 1\right)!}\
\geq\
\color{#ff0000}{\large 2^{n}\,\left(n + 1\right)!}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding $(n+1)^{(n+1)}$ for a few terms.