# Prove that $\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n \gt n! \gt \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n \qquad n\ge 6 $

Tags: inequality, induction

> $$\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n \gt n! \gt \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n \qquad n\ge 6 $$

I tried it prove it by mathematical induction but failed  .
For $n=6$
$$(3)^6 \gt 6!$$
Now for $n=k$
$$\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^k \gt k!$$
Now for $n=k+1$
$$\left(\frac{(k+1)}{2}\right)^{k+1} \gt (k+1)!$$
$$\left(\frac{(k+1)}{2}\right)^{k} \gt 2(k!)$$

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317022/prove-that-an-left-frac-n3-rightn-lt-n-lt-left-fracn2-rightn?rq=1

Comment: "$\left(\frac{(k+1)}{2}\right)^{k+1} \gt (k+1)!$" why would you *say* this?  This is what you need to prove.  You can't assume it.

Comment: @fleablood I assumed it but I didn't state that I have proved it  . I was just trying to prove for $(k+1)!$ as we do in mathematical induction.

Comment: @Dr.MV, Stirling's Formula does not give a proof.

Comment: @Dr.MV You get just an approximation, not a proof, if you don't write out all terms, and if you do that it will be a mess.

Comment: @wythagoras I've provided a solution that uses two methodologies; (i) a proof by induction and (ii) a proof using simple bounds on Stirling's formula.  It is not at all "messy" as you conjectured.  ;-)) -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV I take my words back (+1 to your answer), but I call $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n$ (and the other series expansion)  Stirling's formula, but I don't call the other formula's Stirling's formula.

Comment: @whythagoras That is fair.  And thank you for the up vote!  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 4):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**  Proof by Induction

> **PRIMER:**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using Bernoulli's Inequality that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is a monotonically increasing sequence.  Therefore, its minimum is $2$ when $n=1$.  It is clearly bounded by $3$ as can be shown applying the binomial theorem and applying simple estimates.
>
> $$\begin{align}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&=1+1\\\\&+\frac1{2!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\frac{1}{3!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)+\cdots +\frac{1}{n!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{n-1}n\right)\\\\&\le 1+1+\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\\\\&\le 3\end{align}$$

Now, assume for some $n>6$ that $\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n\ge n!\ge \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n$.  Then, for $n+1$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{n+1}&=\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\,\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n\,\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\\\
&\ge \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\,n!\,\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\\\
&=(n+1)!\,\frac12 \,\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\\\
&\ge (n+1)!
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown, and

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)^{n+1}&=\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)\,\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n\,\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\\\
&\le \left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)\,n!\,\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\\\
&=(n+1)!\,\frac13 \,\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\\\
&\le (n+1)!
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**  Proof Invoking Bounds of Stirling Formula

We can use the bounds found from development of [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation) (See "Advanced Calculus, John Olmsted, 1961, pp. 490-491.)

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{12(n+1)}\right)\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\le n!\le \left(1+\frac{1}{12(n-2)}\right)\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \tag 1$$

for $n\ge 3$.

For the left-hand side of $(1)$, we write

$$\begin{align}
n!&\ge \left(1+\frac{1}{12(n+1)}\right)\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{1}{12(n+1)}\right)}\color{green}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{3}{e}\right)^n}\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n\\\\
&\ge \color{blue}{(1)}\,\color{green}{(1)}\,\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n\\\\
&=\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n
\end{align}$$

For the right-hand side of $(1)$, we write

$$\begin{align}
n!&\le \left(1+\frac{1}{12(n-2)}\right)\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\\\\
 &=\color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{1}{12(n-2)}\right)}\color{green}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\,\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^n}
\,\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n
\end{align}$$

The function $f(x)=\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{3}{e}\right)^x$ can easily be shown to monotonically decrease for $x>\frac{1}{2\log(e/2)}$.  Therefore, for $x=n\ge 6$, the function is less than $f(6)<\frac{48}{49}$.  And inasmuch as $ 1+\frac{1}{12(n-2)}\le \frac{49}{48}$ for $n\ge 6$, we have

$$\begin{align}
n!&\le \left(1+\frac{1}{12(n-2)}\right)\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\\\\
 &=\color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{1}{12(n-2)}\right)}\color{green}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\,\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^n}
\,\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n\\\\
&\le \color{blue}{\left(\frac{48}{49}\right)}\,\color{green}{\left(\frac{49}{48}\right)}\,\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{k+1}2\right)^{k+1}&=\frac {k+1}2\left(\frac {k+1}2\right)^k\\
&>\frac{k+1}2\left[\left(\frac k2\right)^k+\binom k1\left(\frac k2\right)^{k-1}\frac12\right]\\
&>\frac{k+1}2[k!+k!]\\
&=(k+1)!
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Still another approach is to exploit creative telescoping. We have
$$ n = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) \tag{1}$$
hence it follows that
$$ n! = \frac{n^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k}\in\left(\frac{n^n}{e^{n-1}},\frac{n^n}{2(9/4)^{n-2}}\right)\tag{2} $$
for any $n\geq 2$.

Comment: I heard some news to day about an earthquake in central Italy. Everything ok?

Comment: @imranfat: we had some moments of fear but my place is out of real-mess-zone, luckily.

Comment: That's good....